# Change owner of a Gerrit change

Tags: git, gerrit, owner

I am creating an auto-integrate script which takes in changes and source and destination branches.

The problem is that once its pushed to Gerrit the owner is me.

I want to change it to the author or committer.

Is it possible to change the owner to someone else?

If not, is it possible to give abandon, Topic etc rights to the committer for a change. The reason I want to change the Gerrit owner is to give the authors/committers access to abandon etc.

Comment: Do yu simply want to change the owner of a commit?

Comment: Hey I want to change the owner of an existing gerrit link.

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't change the owner of an existing Gerrit change. You can grant the abandon, review, submit, etc permissions to any Gerrit specific group or person but not to the committers of the change (in general).

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. Would you know how we can grant the permissions to abandon/rebase/change topic etc? Thanks!

Comment: You need to have "Administrate Server" rights. Go to: Projects > List > All-Projects  or a specific project > Access > Edit and add permissions. More info: https://gerrit-documentation.storage.googleapis.com/Documentation/2.12.2/access-control.html#access_categories